# csv file format for setting table rate in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, csv, table-rates

I need to set special shipping cost for 1-3 business days(first 5 kg) for the states Dubai & Sharjah in UAE, but I don't know how to write it in the csv file. Do anyone know the format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Shipping Methods >> Table Rates`

[image]

Export sample file that is already entered in `Table Rates`  from export button.

After exporting you can see rules something like below and you can enter as per your requirement.

[image]

`1-3 business days(first 5kg)` for this condition you have to write `promotion rules`

[image]

Read this blogs:

1. [Cart Price Rules](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html)
2. [Cart Price Rules](http://blog.belvg.com/cart-price-rules-section-in-magento-2-0.html)

Comment: chirag thnkz for the reply. bt this is not i want. i have already imported the csv file. now i need to add extra conditions. that i specified in the question.

Comment: `1-3 business days(first 5kg) ` for this condition you have to write `promotion rules`

Comment: i dont know about promotion rules. where can i do it?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Can possible to apply a charge in 'Order Total'?

Comment: Yes, but you need to customize it.